# Explode() function is leading to cannot handle a non-unique multi-index! error

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-explode

I have a dataframe with columns which has list values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'var1': ['[2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0]', '[1.0, 5.0]', '[2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0]', '[6.0]', '[2.0, 5.0]', '[2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0]', '[3.0]', '[1.0, 5.0]'], 
                   'var2': ['[A4003250601, A4003250601, A4003250601, A4003250601]','[A4002000401, A9262000201]', '[A4003250601, A4003250601, A4003250601, A4003250601]', '[A4001800801]', '[A4002000401, A9262000201]', '[A4003250601, A4003250601, A4003250601, A4003250601]', '[A4001800801]', '[A4002000401, A9262000201]'], 
                   'var3': ['[335.764, 335.764, 335.764, 335.764]', '[191.0, 310.0]', '[335.764, 335.764, 335.764, 335.764]', '[240.0]', '[191.0, 310.0]', '[335.764, 335.764, 335.764, 335.764]', '[240.0]', '[191.0, 310.0]'], 
                   'var4':['[15659839, 15659839, 15659839, 15659839]', '[15659891, 15659891]', '[15659839, 15659839, 15659839, 15659839]', '[15659891]', '[15659891, 15659891]', '[15659839, 15659839, 15659839, 15659839]', '[15659891]', '[15659891, 15659891]'], 
                   'var5':['[PMAC, PMAC, PMAC, PMAC]', '[SUNDARAM FASTENERS LTD (GUMMIDIPOONDI), AUTOLEC DIVISION , SUNDARAM FASTENERS LTD (GUMMIDIPOONDI), AUTOLEC DIVISION ]', '[PMAC, PMAC, PMAC, PMAC]', '[SUNDARAM FASTENERS LTD (GUMMIDIPOONDI), AUTOLEC DIVISION ]', '[SUNDARAM FASTENERS LTD (GUMMIDIPOONDI), AUTOLEC DIVISION , SUNDARAM FASTENERS LTD (GUMMIDIPOONDI), AUTOLEC DIVISION ]', '[PMAC, PMAC, PMAC, PMAC]', '[SUNDARAM FASTENERS LTD (GUMMIDIPOONDI), AUTOLEC DIVISION ]', '[SUNDARAM FASTENERS LTD (GUMMIDIPOONDI), AUTOLEC DIVISION , SUNDARAM FASTENERS LTD (GUMMIDIPOONDI), AUTOLEC DIVISION ]'],
                   'var6': [20221031,20221031,20221101, 20221101, 20221101, 20221102,20221102,20221102],
                   'var7':[0.8544,0.42, 0.8544, 0.729,0.42, 0.8544, 0.729, 0.42],
                   'var8':[1200,1000,1200,900,1000,1200,900,1000]})
```

While trying to get the list elements in a separate rows, I am getting error as **ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!**

The **code** I am using:

```
(df.set_index(['var6', 'var7', 'var8']) 
       .apply(lambda col: col.astype(str).str.split(',')
       .explode())
       .reset_index()
       .reindex(df.columns, axis=1))
```

**Note:** I have checked and the code works fine prior to explode. But once explode() is used the error pops up.

Comment: You have duplicated indices after explode `var8`, `1200` for instance.

Comment: @hide1nbush but I am doing a set_index of 3 columns(var6, var7 and var8). These three have all unique values when taken together.

Comment: Still, you may generate duplicated pairs. For instance, `(20221031, 0.42, 1200)`.

Comment: I checked for my table and when we take var6, var7 and var8 together, they all are unique combination . there are duplicates only if var7 and var8 are taken

Comment: @hide1nbush, is there a way around this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want exactly...... It's better that you could append sample input&output in the thread. In my understanding, `df.explode(["var6", "var7", "var8"]).reset_index().reindex(df.columns, axis=1)` should work since you want to explode on those three columns.